# networkState, readyState not working for audio stream

Tags: javascript, streaming, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I’m trying to check for an audio stream, to see if it is active. The server is on and streaming audio or it is off and not streaming. I found two methods, .networkState and .readyState, that work against an audio tag or an Audio() object. Things look okay when the stream is off and never been listened to (not in browser cache). I have both methods being executed every 4s to catch any change in the status of the stream because I want to continuously monitor for any change and update the web page.

The trouble is that I can’t get either method to correctly update the status of the stream once it has changed, that is, from off to on or on to off. I have to refresh the page to get a real update. Then, after you’ve listened to the stream and it is cached, it always shows as ‘on’.

Why don’t either of these methods correctly detect the change of the stream? Is there a way to force a check against the actual object instead of the cached object?

(excuse my code - I quickly chunked this together and I am a newbie) (I tried more than shown below, but tried to make this post succinct.)

```js
<script>
var myTimerVar = setInterval(myTimer, 4000);
var myFunctionVar = setInterval(myFunction, 4000);
// var aud = new Audio('http://myserver.com:8080/live.mp3');

function myTimer() {
    var acheck = document.getElementById("myAudio").networkState;
    if (acheck == 1) {
      document.getElementById("netstate").innerHTML = "ONLINE " + acheck;
      document.getElementById("netstate").style.backgroundColor = "MediumSeaGreen";
    }
    else if (acheck == 3) {
      document.getElementById("netstate").innerHTML = "OFFLINE " + acheck;
      document.getElementById("netstate").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
}

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myAudio").readyState;
    if (x == 0) {
      document.getElementById("readystate").innerHTML = "OFFLINE " + x;
      document.getElementById("readystate").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else if (x == 4) {
      document.getElementById("readystate").innerHTML = "ONLINE " + x;
      document.getElementById("readystate").style.backgroundColor = "MediumSeaGreen";
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="http://myserver.com:8080/live.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<!-- this is what does not update correctly on the page -->
<p>StreamN0 is: <span id="netstate">OFFLINE</span></p>
<p>StreamR0 is: <span id="readystate">OFFLINE</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have both methods being executed every 4s to catch any change in the status of the stream

Firstly, consider using the [`readystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange) event instead.

```
const readyStates = {
  0: 'HAVE_NOTHING',
  1: 'HAVE_METADATA',
  2: 'HAVE_CURRENT_DATA',
  3: 'HAVE_FUTURE_DATA',
  4: 'HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA'
}

document.querySelector('audio#myAudio').addEventListener('readystatechange', (e) => {
  document.querySelector('#readyState').innerText = readyStates[e.readyState];
});
```

> The trouble is that I can’t get either method to correctly update the status of the stream once it has changed, that is, from off to on or on to off.

What I *think* you're asking about is whether or not the stream is actually live... online or not.  That's not what the `readyState` indicates.  The browser doesn't actually know that you're playing a live stream.  It assumes that the data it's cached is intended to be played.  A `readyState` of `HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA` (`4`) just means that the browser thinks it's sufficiently buffered the media, and the rate of which it's buffered means it thinks it can [continue to play without interruption](http://The%20trouble%20is%20that%20I%20can%E2%80%99t%20get%20either%20method%20to%20correctly%20update%20the%20status%20of%20the%20stream%20once%20it%20has%20changed,%20that%20is,%20from%20off%20to%20on%20or%20on%20to%20off.).

The events you're probably looking for include:

- [`playing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/playing)
- [`waiting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/waiting)
- [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended)
- [`emptied`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/emptied)
- [`stalled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/stalled)

Comment: I couldn't get this to do anything.  I'm not sure if it would work in all cases anyway.  Like if the stream is not online and the user loads the page, then 2 min later the stream comes online.  Would it detect both states w/o user interaction?  Also, can you explain this "readyStates[e.readyState]"?  I don't understand the syntax or the connection to 'readyState'.

Comment: @Justin No, of course it isn't going to detect when your stream comes online 2 minutes later.  That's not at all the responsibility of the player on the page.  That's up to your code to decide if it wants to retry or not.  You're conflating the state of the player and its current stream, with status of a resource on a server.  They're not the same thing.  For the syntax of `readyStates[e.readyState]`, all I'm doing there is logging the name of the state rather than its integer value.

Comment: Thanks, Brad, for the clarification of conflating the player state and the resource status - very helpful.  What I meant by the syntax of `readyStates[]` is how does the syntax work.  I know it is changing the page content.  I can't make the connection between "e" (the return value of readyStates) and "readyState" (the span ID).  I couldn't get any reaction out of your sample code.  And, would ".networkState" not be appropriate at all here?

Comment: To be sure, then, I do have a retry in my code `setInterval` in an attempt to detect the stream state at any given time.  And, would ".networkState" not be appropriate at all here?

Comment: @Justin What specifically are you trying to show on the page?  If you just want to test the stream, you could issue a `HEAD` request via the Fetch API to determine the basic status.  If your application needs to determine in realtime whether or not your stream is up and running, you could actually push a status update to a client over server-sent events (SSE).

Comment: I just need to show some text, like "stream is on".  I tried using fetch (which I'm not very familiar with) but came up against CORS and mixed content roadblocks, I think, because the stream is on a subdomain (diff IP) and not HTTPS.  I might be able to use SSE, but the audio server is very restricted.

Comment: @Justin What does "stream is on" mean to you, though?  Does it mean the server itself is accepting connections?  That the server has a stream at a particular mountpoint?  That the stream at that mountpoint is decodeable and playable in the current browser?  All these things have different methods of testing them.  If you're having CORS issues, be sure to set the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers on your server so that it's readable by the client.

Comment: I would say the most important thing is:  That the server has a stream at a particular mountpoint.  I'm trying to find the file "live.mp3" (mountpoint) on the server.

Comment: @Justin Then, make a `HEAD` request with `fetch()`.  Configure your server to allow cross-origin requests.